# Updating the date format in sqland combining two fields into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I received date from a friend, but i need to change it to a line with my tables structure.

**Data received.**

```
Initial,Surname, Date_of_birth      ,      Accno
AD     ,Halute , 01Apr1978:00:00:00 ,      1111111111
```

**My table**

```
Surname & Initial, Date_of_Birth, Accno
Halute AD        , 01/04/1978   , 111111111
```

The question is how do I go about converting the new data to look like mine

I tried the below query, I got this error message.

```
SELECT
    surname+' '+INITIALS as 'Surname & Initial'
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(DATETIME, STUFF(Date_of_Birth, CHARINDEX(':', Date_of_Birth), 1, ' '), 100), 103) AS Date_of_Birth
    ,Accno
FROM BackScanning
```

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 The conversion of a varchar data
>   type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: It would be great if you can put the DDL of your table (My Table). Also, the "Data received" is in csv, xls, or somethingelse?

Comment: The DDL of Data Received is all Varchar(50) and My Table as follows Surname & initial Nvarchar(50), Date of Birth Nvarchar(10),Accno Nvarchar 10

Comment: 1. Don't use comments to add details, instead, edit your question. 2. **Always** use proper data types - never save a date values as char, varchar etc. use the date data type.

Comment: Hi @ZoharPeled, thank you noted, both these tables were inherited. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think this is what you want.

```
SELECT 'Halute' + ' AD' AS Surname_Initial, 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(DATETIME, '01Apr1978 00:00:00',100), 103) AS Date_of_Birth,
        '111111111' AS Accno
```

Above query gives you single records. To select from your table, it should like this -

```
SELECT
    Surname_Initial
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(DATETIME, STUFF(Date_of_Birth, CHARINDEX(':', Date_of_Birth), 1, ' '), 100), 103) AS Date_of_Birth
    ,Accno
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Hi @Krishnraj Rana, I have about 9million records that need to be update?

Comment: @user3309798: Did you try my query by putting actual column name ?

Comment: I did, it just gave me the following, `SurnameInitial,01/04/2016,11111111111` for all records

Comment: @user3309798: It is because i have added static value provided by you. Just add your actual column name like this - `Select Surname_Initial, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(DATETIME, STUFF(Date_of_Birth, CHARINDEX(':', Date_of_Birth), 1, ' '),100), 103) AS Date_of_Birth, Accno From YourTable`

Comment: @user3309798: This type of error occurred because some of your records from `Date_of_Birth` column contain invalid dates for exa. `31Apr1985`. Well April month never have 31 date, right. So to get to this invalid dates, just execute select query with `top` clause like this - `Select top 100 accno, ... from your_table`.

Comment: THANK YOU, got the data matching. Thank you all for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

`create table #temp (col01 varchar(50), dob date);`

```
with cte as (
SELECT 'AD' AS INITIAL
        ,'Halute' as SURNAME
        ,'01Apr1978:00:00:0' as date_of_birth
)
insert into #temp (col01, dob)
select surname+' '+initial as 'Surname & Initial'
    ,CONVERT(date,substring(date_of_birth,1,9))
    --,date_of_birth
from   cte
```

I used substring as your sample is '01Apr1978:00:00:0'